# iOS App Store provisioning profile doesn't have Devices included

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am looking at two identical provisioning profiles made for iOS Distribution in App Store. One of them has list of Devices that are provisioned. Another one does not.
Both were created in same way:

1. create app id
2. create certificate **iOS Distribution (App Store and Ad Hoc)**
3. create provisioning profile **App Store** with app store certificate

Is there a way to still have App store provisioning profile with devices list? Why exact same profile had devices before (few months ago) and now not anymore? See images for reference.
If I create Ad Hoc profile, can I then upload it to AppStore without re-signing?

First one has it:
[image]

This one does not:
[image]

Comment: An App Store distribution profile would not contain devices; it doesn't need to.  Only an ad-hoc distribution profile needs to contain devices.  Perhaps apple was erroneously including them previously and has now fixed this?

Comment: @Paulw11 does that mean I can not use AppStore profile anymore for testing? Like the one that has devices listed? Which was convenient - it's signed for app store, but testers could test it and no re-sign needed for AppStore

Comment: Use TestFlight?  AFAIK it was never intended that you would perform ad-hoc testing with an App Store build.